# Double click on text using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

How can I get Selenium to double click on 'Res.' from the html below:

```
<g class = "text">
    <text x="0" y="0">
        <tspan x="24" y="43" data-chunk-id="0">Cardiovasc </tspan>
        <tspan x="93.025390635" y="43" data-chunk-id="1">Res. </tspan>
    </text>
```

I am close, when I run the following code:

```
word = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Res.')]")
actionChains = ActionChains(browser)
actionChains.double_click(word).perform()
```

'Cardiovasc' is what is double clicked in the website. 
How can I make my element more specific so it double click's on Res.?
My ultimate goal is to highlight the text but I first need get selenium pointing at the right place.

**UPDATE**
When I print the text of the element it is correct but the problem is that the location is the same for each word in the sentence.

```
>>> print(word.text)
Res.
>>> print(word.location)
{'x': 33, 'y': 117}
```

If I set the element to the word 'Cardiovasc' which is directly before 'Res.'

```
word = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Cardiovasc')]")
```

I get it pointing to the correct word but the same location:

```
>>> print(word.text)
Cardiovasc
>>> print(word.location)
{'x': 33, 'y': 117}
```

I've also tried finding the element on unique id but get the same result:

```
word = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-chunk-id='1']")
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to select the particular `tspan` element you might try:

```
word = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tspan[contains(., 'Res.')]")
```

or to test for the content directly (ignoring any leading/trailing white space):

```
word = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tspan[normalize-space(.)='Res.']")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But both of those gave a similar error message:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//tspan[normalize-space(.)='Res.']"}

Comment: @Ziska220 is the element really `tspan`?

Comment: ah, it's inside an SVG image - this might help: `//*[local-name() = 'svg']//tspan[normalize-space(.)='Res.']`

Comment: Hmm still giving the error. It's also inside a 'g' and 'text' element. Should I include those?

Comment: the `//` should take care of that (it selects any descendant, not just direct children), but it seems that one has to be more verbose: `//*[local-name() = 'svg']//*[local-name() = 'tspan' and normalize-space(.)='Res.']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138370/discussion-between-ziska220-and-ewcz).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing versions of Selenium and changing to an older version of Firefox. In addition, I have to run this code on my 'Early-2015' MacbookAir and not my 2017 MacbookPro (this issue could probably be solved with setting screen resolution).

Here are the versions I used:

Selenium 3.1.0

Firefox 47.0.2

Gecko Driver (I have v0.12-15 installed in the environment.)